# Having trouble declaring and initializing a global structure

Tags: c, struct, global-variables, global

In h.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}XS;

typedef struct
{
    XS x_array[10];
}YS;

extern YS y;
```

In m.c file:

```
#include "h.c"

int void main()
{
    YS y = malloc(sizeof(YS));

    y.x_array[0].x = 1;

    free(y);
    return 0;
}
```

This won't compile and I cannot figure out why. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: `int void main()`?????

Comment: was a typo it's actually just int main(void)

Comment: BTW, what are the compiler errors? Did you _read_ them?

Comment: Please read how `struct`s, `malloc` and pointers work in C. There seem to be some basics missing (no offence), you still have to learn.

Comment: we usually `malloc()` on/ into a pointer, you know....

Comment: Here is the compiler error:Error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'YS' from type 'void *'

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, we `malloc` an _object_. But we use a pointer to point to that object ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Sir, can't agree more, but that seems to much for someone who just wrote above code. :)

Comment: @Olaf Hopefully next question "Object??? in C??" . You know what I mean. :)

Comment: To the OP --> no need to malloc, `y` is not a pointer here.

Comment: Ok so I would first have to create a ptr to the address of "extern YS y" in my m.c.

Then I would have to use that ptr like this in m.c:
y_ptr = malloc(sizeof(YS));

Comment: The `extern` doesn't have any effect here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Read the standard! I uses the term "object" very well. "Object" is not necessarily the sae as in OOPLs (although there are similarities).

Comment: @Olaf Sir, I think I'm misunderstood. I did not point any of my comments for (or from) you. It was for OP. That's why I said I agree to you in very first place. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @Olaf : Is this heading in the right direction... in my main function I have YS *y_ptr = &y and then I go on to y_ptr = malloc(sizeof(YS))

Comment: malloc return void* you must cast it to target type. YS \*y = (YS\*)malloc(sizeof(YS));

Comment: @MohamedElHousseine Oh I see now!

Comment: you can use malloc only with pointer type

Comment: @user3413515: Sorry, but SO is no tutorial site. While this is basically right, I do not know if you really understood the concept, the whys, wheres and hows. This is too much of C basic knowledge to just give you a pattern; you really need to **understand** this. It's much like mathematics. Really: no offence!)

Comment: @MohamedElHousseine: **Never** cast `void *` to/from other pointer types in C! C is not C++.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Sorry, I really though you mean me with "@olaf". Stupid me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

your main must look like this:

```
#include "h.h"
int main()
{
    YS *y = malloc(sizeof(YS));

    y->x_array[0].x = 1;

    free(y);
    return 0;
}
```

In h.h file:

```
#ifndef H_H
#define H_H
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}XS;

typedef struct
{
    XS x_array[10];
}YS;

#endif
```

Comment: **Never** cast `void *` to/from other pointer types in C! C is not C++.

Comment: @Olaf that is not correct! you can't use malloc without casting! except your target type is void*

Comment: You are so very wrong! You confuse C with C++. I C you should not cast, in C++ you have to! Both fior reasons of type-safety. There have been so many Q&As here already. Just search for them! If your compiler complains, get a standard-compliant one.

Comment: @Olaf respect I'm c++ developer and used to handle c code like c++ code. We can cast but is not recomanded

Comment: Just to clarify: C and C++ are different languages. You should not confuse them and never compiler C code with a C++ compiler. And: if you use the C programming style in C++ you are doing something wrong. And vice-versa. Even for same syntax, semantics might differ (sontimes quite subtle).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:
1. In h.c, you declare `YS y` as `extern` which means the compiler expects a external global declaration for y. But you've declared it as a local object in m.c

2. You are trying to `malloc` for a static object.

h.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
}XS;

typedef struct
{
    XS x_array[10];
}YS;

YS *y;
```

m.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "h.h"

extern YS *y;

int void main()
{
    y = malloc(sizeof(struct YS));

    y->x_array[0].x = 1;

    free(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I agree this is a bad idea, the local declaration is not a problem actually, as it just shadows the global one (maybe the compiler will warn), but that is no error, as the global object is never used. However, you snippet is also wrong. It is lacking a definition. `extern` inhibits a tentative definition; you better swap the two declarations of `YS`.

Comment: Inside malloc(sizeof()) it should be just YS right?